# Why does Bashrc alias fails to process code inside $ sign?

Tags: bash, macos, alias

I use the command

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

very ofter.

I decided to create an alias for it in .bashrc file.
I added the following line:

```
alias docker-stop-all="docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)"
```

Unfortunately, when I run it I get the following errors:

> zsh: command not found: f18857f77255

> zsh: command not found: 9c03aed54bab

> zsh: command not found: a198f34e39fc

> zsh: command not found: 32703a2209fd

However, when I just type the command in terminal, it works well. Do you know what is the reason for it?

Comment: Replace `$` with `\$`?

Comment: The question is about `zsh`; don't use the `bash` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how the newlines output by `docker ps` are handled.

`docker ps` outputs a sequence of newline-separated container ids. When used with

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

those newlines are treated by the shell as arbitrary whitespace for word-splitting purposes, and are removed, so that `docker stop` receives each id as a separate argument.

When you use double quotes for the alias definition

```
alias docker-stop-all="docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)"
```

`docker ps` is first run when the alias is *defined*, so the definition itself contains literal newlines. The result is that if the output is

a
b
c

then the alias expands to

```
docker stop a
b
c
```

Only the first container id is treated as an argument to `docker stop`; the rest are parsed as subsequent command names.

You *want* the `docker ps` command to be deferred until you use the alias; the easiest way to do that is to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
alias docker-stop-all='docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)'
```

Now the alias contains a literal command substitution, which will be parsed and evaluated following each alias expansion.